# Storing hidden values (IDs) in a listbox with values with Java Applications

Tags: java

I don't know if this is possible.

```
// Adding values to a listbox in Java
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
model.addElement("One");
model.addElement("Two");
list1.setModel(model);
```

What I want is somehow to store a value in the listbox as follows:

```
If user clicks on "One", ID=1 is retrieved.
If user clicks on "Two", ID=2 is retrieved.
```

I know how to retrieve the selected value, but I want to store a hidden ID.
This is easy to do with web based programming but not sure if it could be done with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is eminently possible, but the key is not to store Strings in the Model but instead objects that hold Strings and id's, etc.

Assuming a class, MyFoo that holds these fields.

```
DefaultListModel<MyFoo> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
model.addElement(new MyFoo("One", 1));
model.addElement(new MyFoo("Two", 2));
list1.setModel(model);
```

The only kicker is that you'll want to give the JList a ListCellRenderer that displays only the Number String, but that's not hard to do, and the tutorials will show you how to do this.

Another solution is to create a `HashMap<String, Integer>` that maps the number String with its related int, but I like the first solution better as it seems cleaner to me.

Comment: I'm having some trouble implementing the ListCellRenderer for this. could you direct me here?

Comment: @D.Rattansingh: Have you checked the renderer section of the tutorial which you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)? If you're still stuck after attempting instructions from this, then please create your [sscce](http://sscce.org) showing your attempt as an edit to your question above, and let's see how it can be improved.